# How to process files oldest to newest bash?

Tags: bash, sed

**Overview**

I have a bunch of log files which rollover when they reach a certain size. Each line in the log file has a bunch of logger formatting and then some interesting information. I want to take those files and remove the formatting from the beginning of each line and then put the output of all of that into a single file. I will then eventually take that one file and load it into another application manually.

**Details**

The file structure looks something like this:

```
logs
 |-- modules
 |    +-- ...
 |-- application.log
 |-- gc.log
 |-- gc.log.1
 |-- ...
 +-- gc.log.10
```

So `logs` contains subdirectories and multiple log files. The ones I am insterested are `gc.log*`.

Each `gc.log*` file rolls over to a new file when it gets full. `gc.log` is always the newest and it goes up to `gc.log.10` being the oldest (by default there are only 10, max version 9, but this is configurable).

A typical `gc.log*` contains thousands of entries like:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 | 1164752.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |    [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |       [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |        Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]
...
```

(Yes these are G1 GC logs from the Oracle JVM. It is these that I need in a separate file so I can graph with GCViewer)

Once I have stripped out the formatting I need it to look like:

```
1164752.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
   [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
      [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
       Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]
```

**What I have so far**

So far I have learnt that I shouldn't be using `ls` to get the files. I found this on another SO question (sorry I forgot which one) [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

I am using the following to list the files and then sort them from oldest to newest:

```
find "$logDir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'gc.log*' | sort -Vr
```

Which gives me the following:

```
./gc.log.10
./gc.log.9
./gc.log.8
./gc.log.7
./gc.log.6
./gc.log.5
./gc.log.4
./gc.log.3
./gc.log.2
./gc.log.1
./gc.log
```

The command I have to remove the formatting is:

```
sed -e 's/^.\{7\}[|].\{10\}[|].\{21\}[|] //g'
```

(I may just use `cut -c43-`)

**Problem**

I'm not sure how to get the output from `sort` into `sed`.

The following doesn't work when the file name (or `$logDir`) has spaces:

```
find "$logDir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'gc.log*' | sort -Vr | xargs sed -e "s/^.\{7\}[|].\{10\}[|].\{21\}[|] //g"
```

I'm also going to need to take the output from `sed` and then concatenate that all together into a single file.

**Question**

Finally the question:

- How can I list certain files in a directory in reverse natural number sort order, remove a pattern from the beginning of each line in those files and lastly concatenate the results into a single file (in bash)?

Comment: Do you have GNU `find`? If so, we can use `-printf` to put modification time into the output, assuming that's _really_ what you want to sort by.

Comment: BTW, writing an essay rather than a well-isolated question (or pair/trio of them) is somewhat less than ideal. The chances that someone else will want to be able to safely sort arbitrarily-named files by mtime in a shell script are very, very high, so a question that asks only about that (if none already existed on that topic) would get a whole lot of views/upvotes/answers. Asking how to do all of A, B and C together means you get a question where answers are useful only to you, because almost nobody will have the exact same file format &c.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry that was a copy paste error. I renamed them during testing. I have updated the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your feedback. I only did this because I read a few other questions and everyone wanted the actual use case instead of what the OP thought they wanted to do in a contrived example.

Comment: It's a balancing act, to be sure.

Comment: wrt `The following doesn't work when the file name has spaces:` - DO you have file names that contain spaces? If so show them in your example instead of making it look like your file names are simply alphabetic with a numeric suffix as it's important.

Comment: @EdMorton, I tend to disagree with writing code that's robust only against expected inputs as opposed to all possible inputs. Things you don't expect are where bugs come from; if you aren't lucky, they end up being serious ones.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I absolutely agree with writing your code robustly almost all of the time but sometimes there's such a huge gulf of complexity between handling the actual input and handling all possible input robustly that it's just not worth it and IMHO this is one of those cases since the OP would have to have a psychotic break to suddenly start introducing newlines, etc. into his logfile names.

Comment: @EdMorton, you may have heard me tell this story before, but I was once at a shop where they lost some very high-value logs (used for billing) after a new piece of software was introduced, intended to generate logs with the same format and naming convention, but with a buffer overflow that could inject arbitrary content into filenames. No psychotic break involved -- but someone didn't quote properly in their cleanup script, and the random memory in question happened to include an `*` surrounded by whitespace. Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your file names are so simple and you're doing so little with them, I'd be tempted to just use the ls output, assuming your files have the intuitive progressive modification times then all you'd need is:

```
ls -rt gc.? gc | xargs awk -F' [|] ' '{print $NF}' > newfile
```

For example:

```
$ cat gc
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 | 1164752.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |    [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |       [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |        Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]
$
$ cat gc.1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 | 1234567.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |    [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |       [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |        Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]
$
$ cat gc.2
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 | 8889996.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |    [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |       [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/05/28 04:40:58 |        Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]

$ ls -rt gc.? gc | xargs awk -F' [|] ' '{print $NF}'
8889996.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
   [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
      [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
       Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]
1234567.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
   [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
      [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
       Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]
1164752.977: [GC pause (young), 0.06583700 secs]
   [Parallel Time:  45.2 ms]
      [GC Worker Start (ms):  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.7  1164752977.9
       Avg: 1164752977.8, Min: 1164752977.7, Max: 1164752977.9, Diff:   0.2]
```

Comment: I think I'll go with something like this as it is easy to understand. Doesn't seem to handle spaces but that's ok for now. Although I am currently using my `find` approach instead of `ls` and it is doing the job (in reality the timestamps are probably ok but for testing I was creating them in various orders).

Answer (score 1):

Since your filenames are fixed, you can simply use brace expansion:

```
for wrapper in wrapper.log{.{9..1},}; do
    echo "$wrapper"
    # do whatever you want to do...
done
```

For your purpose, I guess, this could work too:

```
$ cat wrapper.log{.{9..1},} | sed ...
```

A bit more generic version:

```
$ logfile="wrapper.log" # may contain spaces in filename
$ cat "$logfile"{.{9..1},} | sed ...
```

Comment: Ah I hadn't seen brace expansion before. Seems like it could work but something which I left out was that the number of files is configurable. By default there are only 10 (max version of 9) but this may not always be the case.

Comment: For future readers `wrapper.log` == `gc.log` (there was a copy paste error which has been fixed in the question).

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah I agree sorry. I had run into this while testing hence why I used `sort -Vr` but forgot to update the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it right (and have GNU `find` and `sort`), tell `find` to write the filenames preceded by mtime and separated by NUL characters (the only character which *can't* exist in a file's fully qualified path on UNIX); use `sort` to sort by mtime (rather than trying to mess with names); and then read both pieces of data in:

```
while IFS= read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  sed -e 's/^.\{7\}[|].\{10\}[|].\{21\}[|] //g' <"$filename"
done < <(find "$logDir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %P\0' | sort -nz)
```

This will process files in order from oldest to newest.